# Laravel, how to make duplicate/transfer array?

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it all. I wanted $furnitures and store in $newArray.

```
$furnitures = Furniture::where('id', $variable_holding_id)->get();
```

I tried below codes but produces error "__clone method called on non-object"

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($furnitures as $k => $v) 
{
  $newArray[$k] = clone $v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i don't understand the question correctly. But `$furnitures` is a Collection. Which has the method `toArray()`

So you could do :

```
$newArray = $furnitures->toArray();
```

Comment: yes you understand correctly. this is what im searching for. thanks

Comment: Clone is to Clone a Object, including its properties, constructor etc. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php . You are trying to clone a Collection.